# Conflict between relative and absolute path while using two exe file in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I have one exe say myApp.exe in C:\MyProject folder. It writes logs in logfile say tracefile.log which is also there in C:\MyProject.

Now I have to make a schedule task say Schedule1.exe which will also write in logfile tracefile.log located in C:\MyProject.

Ok, I created Schedule1.exe and kept it in same folder C:\MyProject folder and made schedule taks using this exe.

Problem: Schedule1.exe cannot pick the path of logfile when I give relative path of logfile as ".\tracefile.log". But when I give full path like "C:\MyProject", it picks the logfile path and writes on it.

Please suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the working directory of the process. The working directory of the process is determined at process startup, and may not be the directory that contains the executable. What's more, the working directory can change during the processes life.

It seems to me that you should be giving a full path to these files. You need to get hold of the directory in which the executable lives. That is

```
ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
```

So you should be using this code to name your file:

```
ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'tracefile.log'
```

Comment: Heffernam - You mean to say when I make schedule task using 2nd exe, the exe is executed somewhere else by window task scheduler not in my folder where I have actually kept it?

Comment: @NareshKumar: no, it is **executed** from the folder where you have the .exe file, obviously. But the **working directory** is not guaranteed to be that same folder. When you create a Scheduled Task that runs an .exe file, the "Start in" field sets the initial working directory.